# Cannot see Arduino port up after uploading AVR program

Tags: arduino, port, avr, avrdude

I'm trying to learn how to do AVR programming with my Arduino using AVR libraries. I was able to successfully upload this blink program to my Arduino Micro using the Arduino IDE:

```c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define MS_DELAY 1000

int main (void) {
    // Set 7th bit of DDRC to 1: sets pin 13 to output
    DDRC |= _BV(DDC7);

    while (1) {
        // Set 7th bit of PORTC to 1: sets pin 13 to HIGH
        PORTC |= _BV(PORTC7);

        // Delay for MS_DELAY amount
        _delay_ms(MS_DELAY);

        // Turn off LED
        // Set 7th bit of PORTC to 0: sets pin 13 to LOW
        PORTC &= ~_BV(PORTC7);

        // Delay for MS_DELAY amount
        _delay_ms(MS_DELAY);
    }
}
```

But now my Arduino does not show up on the list of available Arduino boards to connect to in the Arduino IDE, meaning I am unable to write any new programs. I was having trouble before uploading using the `avrdude` commands through the terminal which is why I turned to use the Arduino IDE to help me upload. The Arduino was working fine until the final upload.

I'm on macOS so I checked my `/dev/` directory and the device was not there either (my Arduino would show up as `/dev/cu.usbmodemXXXX`).

How can I fix this? Did I accidentally brick my Arduino? How can I prevent this in the future?

Thank you!

Comment: You destroy bootloader inside MCU. You must burn it back. Please search for topic  **arduino how to burn bootloader**

Comment: How do I go about not destroying the bootloader in the future?

Comment: I don't know. You don't describe how you burn your code to MCU by avrdude. You use some burner? Or not? Basically you can't burn MCU. You must always upload code by some uploader (Arduino IDE for example).

Comment: You overwrote the firmware with USB support, with your own without it.

Comment: I simply typed in the code above into the Arduino IDE as an ino file and hit upload. Like any other Arduino Sketch. That's how I uploaded my code

Comment: @ gre_gor what should i do differently in the future to avoid this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino framework provides its own [main](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp) which performs some initialization, such as calling USBDevice.attach.  You are supplying your own main function, so you are responsible for everything, including USB and other Arduino core initialization.

Alternatively, write an Arduino sketch with setup() and loop() procedures so that you can continue using Arduino provided functionality.  You can still use the lower level avr-libc functionality and manipulate hardware registers directly.

Or just move away from Arduino, then there is no ambiguity - you have to provide everything.  But the Micro is not well suited for this, not if you want to use the USB bootloader.  Unless, as you mentioned, you trigger the bootloader via a hard reset sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I managed to save the board by using the double-click trick.

1. Get a blank Arduino sketch ready
2. Compile it
3. Connect the Arduino to the computer, then double-click the reset button. This will put the Arduino in "bootloader" mode for roughly 8 seconds. The Arduino's onboard LED should start pulsing.
4. Select the Arduino port and click upload. Hopefully, the process is fast enough to upload to the Arduino before it exits "bootloader" mode. If not, double-click the reset button and try again.

I'm leaving this here for others to find a way to unbrick their Arduinos. I'm sure this is a very common mistake for programmers learning AVR programming for the first time.